# another meaning of 'logistical'

Tags: meaning

> Your Honor, Mister Walker has access to resources both monetary and
>   ***logistical***.

The speaker(a prosecutor) thinks Mister Walker is very rich and famous
and his crime is serious.
So, the juddge set higher bail based on what the speaker said.

One translater translated 'logistical into 'reputation'.
But it seems like it doesn't make sense.
Of course I googled it, but I can't get it.

Please help me to understand it perfectly!
(My native language is not English. Please be kind to me. :-))

Comment: *logistical* is an adjective derived from *logistics* which is the science of *getting there fastest with the mostest*.  I don't see why one wouldn't interpret the judge's statement in the obvious way - Mr Walker has ready access to means of flight from justice, means such as trains, planes and automobiles.  The translation of *logistical* to *reputation* seems very strange to me (native BrE speaker).

Comment: Oh, I can understand it now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Twinning [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/logistics) sense 2  'The management of the details of an operation'
with [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/logistics) sense 3 'the detailed planning and organization of any large complex operation' brings to my mind Sherlock's description of Moriarty: 'James Moriarty isn't a man at all. He's a spider, a spider at the centre of a web, a criminal web with a thousand threads and he knows precisely how each and every single one of them dances.' ('Sherlock')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Logistics](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/logistics) is the art of organization. So a defendant with logistical resources will have access to people who know how to get what he wants, whether that is an expert witness (which is desirable for the court) or a fast jet to a country with no extradition (which is not). 'Reputation' is a poor translation in any circumstances; here, it seems clear that the translator has misunderstood the (frankly poor) choice of words.

Answer (score -1):

> logistical is an adjective derived from logistics which is the science of getting there fastest with the mostest. I don't see why one wouldn't interpret the judge's statement in the obvious way - Mr Walker has ready access to means of flight from justice, means such as trains, planes and automobiles. The translation of logistical to reputation seems very strange to me (native BrE speaker). - [High Performance Mark](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/74116/high-performance-mark)